# Number of Orthogonal Vector in a Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces

How to prove that the maximum number of vectors that are mutually orthogonal to each other in a given vector space is equal to the dimension of the vector space?

Comment: Two nonzero orthogonal vectors are linearly independent, aren't they?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's some guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You have to prove it's no more, and that it's no less. For the first, show they're linearly independent. For the second, use Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: @Sou, what does MathJax have to do with this question? It has no mathematical symbols in it at all, it's all plain text.

Comment: This question doesn’t make sense. Do you mean to ask something like “every set of mutually orthogonal vectors contains at most $d$ vectors”?

Comment: @user7530 Oh yes, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @user7530 : I suspect he means "... the **maximal** number of vectors that are orthogonal to each other ..."

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Just in case he/she need reference. If you dont like it i can erase that.

Comment: First of all field of a vector space should be real or complex numbers. Then only inner product is defined.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $V$ is a vector space, a subset $S \subseteq V$ is said to be orthogonal if $\langle v,w\rangle = 0$ for all $v,w \in S$, with $v \neq w$. Prove that if $S$ is orthogonal and $0 \not\in S$, then $S$ is linearly independent. This proves that ${\rm card}(S) \leq \dim V$.